# Cannot connect to the real www.youtube.com

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, youtube

Keep getting error , whenever i connect to youtube.com on chrome, firefox and safari.!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV3jf.png)

Technical details

```
www.youtube.com has asked Chrome to block any certificates with errors, but the
certificate that Chrome received during this connection attempt has an error.
Error type: HSTS failure
Subject: VMware
Issuer: VMware
Public key hashes: sha1/zPBcrobL4QcJEuRiWy5VeozbFYk=sha256/H1zIqHvCaU6Vl3LKB18zv7BMisPuUY0bGATZiDjFlX4=
```

Comment: Is this running inside a VM? Looks like your VM may have tried to act like a proxy for all traffic (ssl or not) instead of letting your VM to connect directly to the web.

Comment: @Darius no i am using Windows 7. i searched everywhere , people saying to update time, and my time is already correct.

Comment: Do you have VMware installed because the error indicates you do

Comment: @Ramhound yes i have installed a long time ago, its working fine after that. but now its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your browser is hitting a proxy on the way to youtube.com. It may be on purpose or not but that's the basic issue.
Youtube does not use a certificate issued by VMWare and issued to VMWare.
Do you have problems with other ssl sites? Try https://www.google.com  - same error?

Update: Looks like you are running a web-server locally on port 90 (try `telnet 80` and `telnet 443` to see if you get responses). For whatever reason youtube.com is resolving to 127.0.0.1 which is an IP address reserved for referring to the local host. These are two separate things that you might want to understand the cause of. You should be aware that you are running a webserver locally - looks like it may have been setup automatically by VMWare but that the OS you are discussing is actually a guest OS (ie it *is* a VM) rather than a host  OS (ie it runs VMs); if you are surprised that you are running a webserver locally than you may have security problems.

Comment: its opening, no error on any other ssl sites its just youtube.

Comment: you at home, work. university?

Comment: i am at home at this time.

Comment: what OS? What IP address does your computer thing www.youtube.com is at?

Comment: windows 7 64bit. when i ping youtube.com its says 127.0.0.1 :/ why is this ?

Comment: check /etc/hosts, on windows that's $INSTALLDRIVE\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts or some such thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12829/discussion-between-arslion-and-ram)

Comment: its default hosts file in windows 7.

Comment: It can't be because YouTube should not be set to you loopback address

Comment: You most likely have some software that redirects www.youtube.com to 127.0.0.1. What that software is, is for you to find out.